# Поля профиля wp-recall

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, wp-plugin

у меня вопрос по wp-recall как вывести поля из профиля, точнее значение, которые ввёл пользователь? Я знаю что можно как-то по meta-key, но как именно. Допустим мне необходимо получить значение поля обо мне, как это сделать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

WordPress API - функция `get_user_meta()`

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]